# Choosing data to compare collected data against

Tags: sampling, multiple-comparisons, representative

I currently have a sample of 30 data points of how long a specific process takes to complete when a particular issue occurs and am looking to compare these times to the times where it doesn't happen to determine if there is a significant difference between the two.

My problem is that the collected data is spread across multiple types of product that all take different times to complete the process. Additionally, the sample collected does not contain a sample of all the types of products ran. As such, the sample is not representative of the population data that I have access to.

Does it make sense in this situation to create a set of data out of the population data that is similar to the collected data set, i.e. create a data set from the overall data set where the product distribution is the same as the collected data set? If yes, would one large sample make sense or one of a similar size? Possible multiple sets to compare? My assumption is that a much larger comparison set, or comparing to multiple sets, would increase the likelihood of a false negative.

Comment: What is population data? I think you do not have it. Then how can you create a dataset out of the population data?

Comment: @user158565 . For instance, imagine I have the time data on all products that were produced and within that there are 5 different product types. I do not have a good way to collect data of when a specific event happens on only a single product type so I've collected data that happens to include only products 2, 3, and 4. Presumably, when making the comparison to the original data set, I should no include products 1 and 5. Assuming that is right, is it most effective to compare to all of the known data for products 2,3,an 4 or should I use a subset of them with a similar number of data points.